# Add class to element when user scrolls up to certain point

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, header

So I have created a sticky header using jQuery, which adds a class to the header when the user scrolls past it. However, I want to know how I can add another class to the header when the user is scrolling back up and reaches 50px before the top of the page? However, I only want this class to add to the header when the user is scrolling back UP, not down, and I want it to remove when the user reaches the top of the page.

This is my code:

```
$(window).scroll(function () {
    if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top && !($('#header').hasClass('sticky-header'))){
            $('#header').addClass('sticky-header');
        } else if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
            $('#header').removeClass('sticky-header');
            }
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var lastScrollTop = 0;
$(window).scroll(function () {
var st = $(this).scrollTop();
if( $(window).scrollTop() > $('#header').offset().top && !($('#header').hasClass('sticky-header'))){
    $('#header').addClass('sticky-header');
}
//this is when user scrolls down: hide the class after 500
if (st > lastScrollTop) {
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 500){
    $('#header').removeClass('another-sticky-header');
    }
}
//this is when user scrools up: before 500 add class
if (st < lastScrollTop) {
    //here 500 is used to make the effect last longer you can make it 50 as you wish to do in OP
    if ( $(window).scrollTop() < 500){
        $('#header').addClass('another-sticky-header');
    }
}
if ($(window).scrollTop() == 0){
    $('#header').removeClass('sticky-header');
    $('#header').removeClass('another-sticky-header');
}

lastScrollTop = st;
});
```

**Note:** this code can be optimized more as certain if can be replace with if else block or ternary operator  and certain inner if can be replaced with && . I hope you can work with that code optimization tweaks.

Comment: One problem!! You scroll up, and it adds the class, but when you scroll back down again the class doesn't remove. :( Is there any way I can get 'another-sticky-header' to remove if the user decides to scroll back down after reaching 500px before the top of the page again? Thank you

Comment: you need to just add another if condition something like: if (st > lastScrollTop) I've  edited my ans try it!

Comment: Thank you, the revised code works really well - I appreciate your help/time